./libpq.so.5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by ./libpq.so.5)
I upgraded my server to Ubuntu 24.04. It was previously running 20.04.
This server is running software that comes with its own Postgres DB environment.
When using psql, it complained that it couldn't find libssl.so.10 and libcrypto.so.10. So I downloaded and installed the package libssl1.0.0_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.20_amd64.deb.
That didn't help much at first.
I then used ldd on psql and saw that it was looking for libssl.so.10 and libcrypto.so.10. In the package, however, these are called libcrypto.so.1.0.0 and libssl.so.1.0.0. I created a symbolic link for each of the files. ldd then displayed the following:
/tester/pgsql/bin/psql: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by /distribution/dacs/pgsql/lib/libpq.so.5)
/tester/pgsql/bin/psql: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by /distribution/dacs/pgsql/lib/libpq.so.5)

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc1a3e5000)
libpq.so.5 => /distribution/dacs/pgsql/lib/libpq.so.5 (0x0000775d90c00000)
libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x0000775d911df000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x0000775d911da000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000775d910f1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000775d90800000)
libssl.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10 (0x0000775d90200000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10 (0x0000775d8fa00000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000775d910ea000)
libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x0000775d910b6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000775d91247000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000775d910af000)

The first two lines says that it can't find the libraries, but the remainder looks like it can find them correctly.
What else can I do to find out what exactly it wants from me?
